# Where are SSH keys for other servers stored? - Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am a newbie to `Ansible`. I have managed to write `playbooks` that set up `Apache`, `Tomcat` and others, all on localhost. I am now trying to move this to other servers to test the playbooks.

I have done the following:
1. Added a section `[webservers]` in `/etc/ansible/hosts` and put the public IP for that instance there.
2. I invoked `ansible-playbook` like so:
`ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1 ansible-playbook -vvvv -s serverSetup.yml`

My questions:
1. Where do I store the public SSH key for the target server?
2. How do I specify which public key to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ansible uses a user to connect to the target machine.

So if your user is ubuntu (`-u ubuntu` in ansible flags) the key will be `~ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` on target machine).

And from the `ansible --help` command you have

> --private-key=PRIVATE_KEY_FILE, --key-file=PRIVATE_KEY_FILE use this file to authenticate the connection

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of other ways it is possible: ansible.cfg, set_fact, environment vars.

### ansible.cfg

You can have an Ansible Config file within your project folder which can state which key to use, using the following:

private_key_file = /path/to/key/key1.pem

You can see an example of an ansible.cfg file here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/ansible.cfg

### set_fact

You can add the key using the set_fact module within your playbook, this can be hardcoded as below or templated:

```
- name: Use particular private key for this playbook
  set_fact: ansible_private_ssh_key=/path/to/key/key1.pem
```

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html

### environment vars

See this stackoverflow post's answer for more information:

[how to define ssh private key for servers fetched by dynamic inventory in files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795607/how-to-define-ssh-private-key-for-servers-fetched-by-dynamic-inventory-in-files)

Answer (score 2):

> Where do I store the public SSH key for the target server?

Wherever makes sense.  Since these are keys that I may use to directly connect to the machine, I usually store them in `~/.ssh/` with my other private keys.  For projects where I'm working on multiple computers or with other users, I store them in [Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html) and have a playbook that extracts them and stores them on the local machine.

> How do I specify which public key to use?

[`group_vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#group-and-host-variables) is a good place to specify `ansible_private_ssh_key`.