# How to manage ssh key file when we want to execute ansible command with github actions

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, ansible, github-actions

I have a github repository, a docker repository and a Amazon ec2 instance. I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline with these tools. The idea is to deploy a docker container to ec2 instance when a push happened to github repository master branch. I have used github actions to build the code, build docker image and push docker image to docker hub. Now I want to pull the latest image from docker hub to remote ec2 instance and run the same. For this I am trying to execute ansible command from github actions. But I need to specify .pem file as an argument to the ansible command. I tried to keep .pem file in github secretes, but it didn't work. I am really confused how to proceed with this.
Here is my github workflow file

```
name: helloworld_cicd
on: 
  push:
    branches: 
      - master
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

    - name: Check out code into the Go module directory
      uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Go Build
      run: go build

    - name: Docker build
      run: docker build -t helloworld .

    - name: Docker login
      run: docker login --username=${{ secrets.docker_username }} --password=${{ secrets.docker_password }}

    - name: Docker tag
      run: docker tag helloworld vijinvv/helloworld:latest

    - name: Docker push
      run: docker push vijinvv/helloworld:latest
```

I tried to run something like

```
ansible all -i '3.15.152.219,' --private-key ${{ secrets.ssh_key }} -m rest of the command
```

but that didn't work. What would be the best way to solve this issue

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795607/how-to-define-ssh-private-key-for-servers-fetched-by-dynamic-inventory-in-files

Comment: You may as well benefit reading the following: https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets

Comment: While I believe you are in good hands with the other commenters, I wanted to point out that a question containing "it didn't work" is never going to get you the help you desire. Please pay special attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) page which has an explicit section saying to avoid that pattern

Comment: sure I will take care

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing what you meant by "*it didn't work*" is that `ansible` expects the private key to be a file, whereas you are supplying a string.

This [page](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#limits-for-secrets) on github actions shows how to use secret files on github actions. The equivalent for your case would be to do the following steps:

1. `gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 my_private_key.pem`
2. Choose a strong passphrase and save this passphrase as a secret in github secrets. Call it `LARGE_SECRET_PASSPHRASE`
3. Commit your encrypted `my_private_key.pem.gpg` in git
4. Create a step in your actions that decrypts this file. It could look something like:

   ```yaml
   - name: Decrypt Pem
     run: gpg --quiet --batch --yes --decrypt --passphrase="$LARGE_SECRET_PASSPHRASE" --output $HOME/secrets/my_private_key.pem my_private_key.pem.gpg
     env:
      LARGE_SECRET_PASSPHRASE: ${{ secrets.LARGE_SECRET_PASSPHRASE }}
   ```
5. Finally you can run your `ansible` command with `ansible all -i '3.15.152.219,' --private-key $HOME/secrets/my_private_key.pem`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use `webfactory/ssh-agent` to add your ssh private key. You can see its [documentation](https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent#usage) and add the following stage before running the `ansible` command.

```
# .github/workflows/my-workflow.yml
jobs:
  my_job:
    ...
    steps:
      - actions/checkout@v2
      # Make sure the @v0.5.2 matches the current version of the
      # action 
      - uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.2
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      - ... other steps
```

`SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` must be the key that is registered in repository secrets. After that, run your `ansible` command without passing the private key file.